# Ubuntu MATE + Meteor ANDROID_HOME SDK Path root issues

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu, meteor, sdk

I tried to build an android apk for my app using Meteor and got some weird ANDROID_HOME errors, tried several solutions but to no avail and now I am stuck with my user having the paths set correctly (aka when I type in the terminal "android", it opens the SDK Manager), but when using sudo or trying to do the same thing as root, it responds: "android: command not found".

Funny thing: Before trying to build the apk I fixed this errors before so I was able to run the app on the device.

I have these lines both in my user and root bashrc and profile files:

```
#AndroidDev PATH
export PATH=${PATH}:~/Android/Sdk/tools/
export PATH=${PATH}:~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Android/Sdk/
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/
export ANDROID_HOME=~/android-sdk-linux/
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/
```

Please help, I'm completely outta ideas now and to fix the Meteor app I need to run sudo meteor add-platform android but it throws ANDROID_HOME errors :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funniest thing, I tried one last thing before giving up on this and it was to modify all paths in my root bashrc file to:

```
#AndroidDev PATH
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/<user>/Android/Sdk/tools/
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/<user>/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/<user>/Android/Sdk/
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/<user>/android-sdk-linux/
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/
```

Basically, the root paths were obviously wrong cuz my android sdk is in my users folder.

I'm posting this because I saw that a lot of people are struggling with this and I myself was awfully frustrated with this issue, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

run these commands in same terminal tab, in which you are making build 
`source ~/.bash_profile` 
`source ~/.bashrc` 
and then run build command.

Comment: Ran them after each change already, but thank you, I forgot to mention it :) I found an answer and posted it here too